# PHPUnit how to test for two conditions

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am new to using PHPUnit, I found out that it is easy to test if given value is desired one using `assertEquals` function but I am not sure how to test for values with more than one condition such as:

```
function myFunction($foo, $bar, $baz)      
{
    if (($foo != 3) AND ($foo != 5)) {
       // something
    }

    if (($bar < 1) OR ($bar > 10)) {
      // something
    }

    if ( (strlen($baz) === 0) OR (strlen($baz) > 10) ) {
      // something
    }
}
```

Can anyone help on how to write unit test for these conditions please ?
Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should create one test case per each possible path of each method/function in your application. In your example you have two possible cases for the first conditional, when $foo is different to 3 and different to 5 and when $foo is equal to 3 or 5. So first you should create two test cases:

```
<?php
class YourClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_Testcase
{
    public function test_when_foo_is_different_to_three_or_five()
    {
        $this->assertEquals('expected result when foo is different from 3 or 5', myfunction(1));
    }

    public function test_when_foo_is_equal_to_three_or_five()
    {
        $expected = 'expected result when foo=3 or foo=5';
        $this->assertEquals($expected, myfunction(3));
        $this->assertEquals($expected, myfunction(5));
    }
}
```

Now you should do the same for the rest of conditionals and permutations. However you made a good discovery by realising that myfunction() method does too many things and it's hard to test and understand so you should move all your conditionals to different methods and test them individually, and then use myfunciton() to call them in the desired order if you absolutely have to. Consider the following approach:

```
function myFunction($foo, $bar, $baz)      
{
    doSomethingWithFoo($foo);    
    doSomethingWithBar($bar);
    doSomethingWithBaz($baz);
}

function doSomethingWithFoo($foo)
{
    if (($foo != 3) AND ($foo != 5)) {
       // something
    }
}

function doSomethingWithBar($bar)
{
    if (($bar < 1) OR ($bar > 10)) {
      // something
    }
}

function doSomethingWithBaz($baz)
{
    if ( (strlen($baz) === 0) OR (strlen($baz) > 10) ) {
      // something
    }
}
```

Testing will help you a lot with this kind of refactoring. Hope this help you clarify a little bit more.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [assertThat](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/assertions.html#assertthat) method.